# Saving model with not nullable relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Consider the following two relations:

User:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id INT NOT NULL,
social_provider_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `user_social_provider_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`social_provider_id`)
REFERENCES `social_provider` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
)
```

Social provider:

```
CREATE TABLE social_provider (
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR NOT NULL )
```

Eloquent models:

```
class User extends Model{
    protected $table = 'user';
    public function socialProvider(){
         return $this->hasOne('/SocialProvider');
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a new User object and save it:

```
$user = new User();
$socialProvider = SocialProvider::find(1);
$user->socialProvider()->save($socialProvider);
$user->save();
```

But I get this exception on the line where I assign the SocialProvder object

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

I tried to save the User object first and then assign the relationship, but obviously this is not possible because of the `NOT NULL` constraint in the definition of the `user` table.

My workaround at the moment is to assign the relationship this way:

```
$user->social_provider_id = $socialProvider->id;
```

But I would like to use Eloquent's features.
How can I save a new model with a not nullable relationship, without having to assign IDs by myself?

**Solution:**
Like @Panagiotis Koursaris suggested, the solution is to use `associate()` instead of `save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = new User();
$socialProvider = SocialProvider::find(1);
$user->socialProvider()->associate($socialProvider);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `User` model, do this

```
public function socialProvider(){
  return $this->hasOne('App/SocialProvider');
}
```